# asp.net: Is there a way to print nothing when value is 0 using eval and currency format?

Tags: asp.net, string-formatting, currency

I'm binding a currency value inside a repeater with:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="amount" Text='<%#Eval("amount","{0:c}")%>' />
```

This works, but prints out $0.00 if the amount is 0.  If I use a format like "{0:#.##}" then nothing is printed out when the value is 0.

Is there a way to modify the "c" format to indicate that nothing should be printed for 0 values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a base page method that returns a string and bind to that instead
eg:

```
/// <summary>
/// Formats a decimal number to the specified format in the settings
/// </summary>
/// <param name="d">Decimal</param>
/// <returns>string representation of the decimal</returns>
protected string FormatDecimal( decimal d )
{
    try
    {
        if ( d == decimal.Zero )
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            return d.ToString(Settings.Instance.DecimalFormat);
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception )
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

then in your aspx:

```
   <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# FormatDecimal((decimal)Eval("amount")) %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: I up-voted this and @Bala R's answer because both are good, but this is my favorite method. I don't like putting this kind of thing in the xml side because it gets too clunky (IMO).

Comment: @Joel - thanks, I like having the page methods too, at least then if there is a problem there is only one place to change it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="amount" Text='<%# Eval("amount","{0:c}").Equals("$0.00") ? "" : Eval("amount","{0:c}")) %>' />
```